# Initializing classes in order

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building an RPG Quest Bot for people to interact with, but I'm not entirely sure how I want to implement progression.

I have a 'Quest' class that contains all the data, such as who is participating, IDs, etc. I've split each area into components. (I.e. You have a beginning component, then let's say a forest, etc..). I'm just not sure how to make the data pass between them.

Example; 
In App.js

```
    try {
        await new BeginComponent(this).execute();
        await new ForestComponent(this).execute();
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
```

And the respective components:

```
export default class BeginComponent {
    constructor(quest) {
        this.quest = quest;
    }

    execute = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.quest.sendMessage("A Quest will start in 3 minutes. Please type !quest to participate.");
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.quest.setAcceptingPlayers(false);
                if (this.quest.getPlayers().size !== 0){
                    this.quest.sendMessage("The Quest has began! Good luck to all participants.");
                    resolve();
                } else {
                    this.quest.sendMessage("Nobody went on the Quest.");
                    reject("Nobody went on the Quest.");
                }
            }, 5000)
        })
    }
}

export default class ForestComponent {
    constructor(quest) {
        this.quest = quest;
    }

    execute = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             //Forest events happen here, etc.
        })
    }
}
```

Now... it works. Each component can update the Quest that is given to them, so it can remove players and change ids and such. But I'm not sure if this is a very good way of doing things.

Comment: Those "component" classes don't seem to have any state on their own, their instances are not used at all, and they have just a single method that is called only once. You might want to convert them into simple functions: `await begin(this); await forest(this);`.

Comment: @Bergi That's true, thank you. Too used to Java, sorry! :P